# Android внутреннее тестирование

Tags: android, google-play

Собираюсь опубликовать своё первое приложение. По советам [google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=ru) решил вначале сделать внутреннее тестирование, что бы понять, будет ли оно работать на других телефонах.

Заполнил описание, возрастные ограничения, цены и распространение.
Выбрал внутреннее тестирование, заполнил там всё.
Однако URL ссылки на приложение не появляется, однако написано, что после публикации приложения будет доступна ссылка.

Что я мог не так сделать? Что ли нужно betta запускать для внутренних?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите скрин со страницы Internal test с развёрнутым пунктом Manage testers.

Comment: @Suvitruf обновил

Comment: Что в итоге получилось?

Answer (score 2):

Привожу цитату со страницы google support:

> Примечание. Если вы публикуете приложение впервые, то внутреннее тестирование станет доступным в течение 48 часов.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=ru

Просто дождитесь появления ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка действительно появляется с задержкой, в моём случае это было полчаса или час.
Саму ссылку можно скопировать в разделе:
Google Play -> Тестирование -> внутреннее тестирование -> вкладка "Количество тестировщиков" -> раздел "Как тестировщики присоединяются к вашему тестированию"